# How do I sort a lazy-loaded list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I have a ul with a lot of list items (around 400) generated in a template with flask. The list is added onto as the user scrolls the website. The list items are simply not displayed in the beginning until they are "loaded".

This is my javascript for the lazy-loading:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const list = document.querySelector(".snow-depth-list-left");
  const itemsToLoad = 15; // Number of items to load at a time
  let startIndex = 0;

  // Function to load more items
  function loadMoreItems() {
    for (let i = startIndex; i < startIndex + itemsToLoad; i++) {
      const listItem = list.children[i];
      if (listItem) {
        listItem.classList.add("loaded"); // Show the loaded item
      } else {
        break; // Stop loading when all items are loaded
      }
    }
    startIndex += itemsToLoad;
  }

  // Initial load
  loadMoreItems();

  // Load more items when scrolling to the bottom of the page
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    if (
      window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight &&
      startIndex < list.children.length
    ) {
      loadMoreItems();
    }
  });
});
```

This made my sorting system obsolete, since it dosent sort with the non-loaded list items.

This is my javascript for the sorting:

```
function sortList(listClass, criteria) {
  const list = document.querySelector(`.${listClass}`);
  const items = Array.from(list.getElementsByTagName('li'));

  items.sort((a, b) => {
    const aValue = a.getAttribute(criteria);
    const bValue = b.getAttribute(criteria);

    if (criteria === 'station') {
      return aValue.localeCompare(bValue);
    } else if (criteria === 'depth' || criteria === 'difference') {
      if (aValue === 'missing') return 1; // Non-numeric values come after numeric values
      if (bValue === 'missing') return -1; // Non-numeric values come after numeric values
      return parseInt(bValue) - parseInt(aValue);
    }
  });

  items.forEach(item => list.appendChild(item));
}
```

I need to use the lazy-loading because the list items are expandable using css animations. Which moves every singe list item under that list item. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Edit:

Not sure that I solved it but I found a solution, a slow one though. I didn't explain this earlier but to make a listitem visible I gave it a clas called .loaded.

The solution is this function, which I call at the end of the sortList function:

```
function addLoadedClassToVisibleItems() {
  // Get all list items with the class "list-item"
  const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');

  listItems.forEach((item) => {
    // Store the original display property
    const originalDisplay = item.style.display;
    
    // Temporarily make the item visible for checking its position
    item.style.display = 'block'; // You can adjust this based on your element's display property

    const itemRect = item.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Check if the item is within the viewport vertically
    if (
      itemRect.top >= 0 &&
      itemRect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    ) {
      // The item is in the viewport, add the "loaded" class
      item.classList.add('loaded');
    }

    // Restore the original display property
    item.style.display = originalDisplay;
  });
}
```

This function stores the original display property of each list item, and then makes them temporarily visible for position checking, and then restores their original display property afterward. This lets the function see and reveal all unloaded listitem that can be seen on the users display.

Also, turns out the list items that hadnt been loaded was being sorted, just not displayed.

If anyone find a better solution, please tell me. With 450 list items it now takes 350ms on my computer to sort all this and run the addLoadedClassToVisibleItems() function.

Comment: Can you sort the items *before* you add them to the template?

Comment: What led you to use lazy-loading? If it was speed, then storing the data outside the UI elements and only transferring it to the UI elements when the data is ready to be displayed could give you sufficient increase in speed.

Comment: @GetSet I have multiple parameters I want the user to be able to sort by different parameters. I have html inputs that calls the sortList function.

Comment: @Yogi Sorry for the unclear question, I'm not sure exactly what it is that is not working. But the problem is that when I sort the list it only sorts/display the loaded in list items. For example: I have a list item that would end up on the top after sorting but dosent, because it's not loaded in.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think what causes the lag is the animation when opening a list item. When a list item is opened it pushes all the list items under it down. Which makes the opening animation laggy. With lazy loading only about 15 listitems are pushed down whic hdosen't lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call your sort method, the nodes in the DOM will change order.
The `loadMoreItems()` function does not account for changed order.
Most likely you're noticing some items having the 'loaded' class after being shuffled by the sort.
I think the easiest approach for you is to reset the 'loaded status' after applying a new sort. Starting to flag items as loaded from the top again.

To do a reset.
Clear all existing `loaded` classes and reset the the counter to 0.

## Example

this is a showcase of how things are behaving,
You'll notice that the loading a next page after shuffling will not pick up the items above the first section of loaded items.

```js
const list = document.querySelector(".snow-depth-list-left");
const itemsToLoad = 5; // Number of items to load at a time
let startIndex = 0;

function resetLoads() {
  // reset all sorting.
  startIndex = 0;
  Array.from(list.children).forEach((child) => child.classList.remove('loaded'))
}

// Function to load more items
function loadMoreItems() {
  const loopCount = Math.min(startIndex + itemsToLoad, list.children.length)
  for (let i = startIndex; i < loopCount; i++) {
    const listItem = list.children[i].classList.add("loaded")
  }
  startIndex += itemsToLoad;
}

function sortList(sortType) {
  const items = Array.from(list.getElementsByTagName('li'));
  items.sort((a, b) => {
    const aValue = a.getAttribute('key');
    const bValue = b.getAttribute('key');
    if (sortType === 'DESC') {
      return parseInt(bValue) - parseInt(aValue);
    } else if (sortType === 'ASC') {
      return parseInt(aValue) - parseInt(bValue);
    } else {
      return Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1
    }
  });
  items.forEach(item => list.appendChild(item));
}

function sortListWithReset(sortType) {
  sortList(sortType) // apply the sorting
  resetLoads() // clear all loaded classes
  loadMoreItems() // laod the first page 
}

// initial load
loadMoreItems()
```

```css
.item {
  background-color: grey;
}

.item.loaded {
  background-color: green;
}

.item.loaded::after {
  content: 'loaded!';
  font-size: .75rem;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: 'no-wrap';
}

.container .list {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.container .buttons {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.container .buttons>* {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div>
      without reseting loaded class:<br>
      <button onclick="sortList('DESC')">sort list desc</button>
      <button onclick="sortList('ASC')">sort list asc</button>
      <button onclick="sortList('Random')">sort list random</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      with reseting loaded class:<br>
      <button onclick="sortListWithReset('DESC');">sort list desc</button>
      <button onclick="sortListWithReset('ASC')">sort list asc</button>
      <button onclick="sortListWithReset('Random')">sort list random</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      load pages: <br>
      <button onclick="loadMoreItems()">load more</button>
      <button onclick="resetLoads()">reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <ul class="snow-depth-list-left">
      <li class="item" key="1">Item 1</li>
      <li class="item" key="2">Item 2</li>
      <li class="item" key="3">Item 3</li>
      <li class="item" key="4">Item 4</li>
      <li class="item" key="5">Item 5</li>
      <li class="item" key="6">Item 6</li>
      <li class="item" key="7">Item 7</li>
      <li class="item" key="8">Item 8</li>
      <li class="item" key="9">Item 9</li>
      <li class="item" key="10">Item 10</li>
      <li class="item" key="11">Item 11</li>
      <li class="item" key="12">Item 12</li>
      <li class="item" key="13">Item 13</li>
      <li class="item" key="14">Item 14</li>
      <li class="item" key="15">Item 15</li>
      <li class="item" key="16">Item 16</li>
      <li class="item" key="17">Item 17</li>
      <li class="item" key="18">Item 18</li>
      <li class="item" key="19">Item 19</li>
      <li class="item" key="20">Item 20</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```